# Visual Studio: Compiler Warnings and errors appear twice in different languages

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have the weird case that in some of my Visual Studio projects the warnings and errors appear multiple times: In my case, one time in english and one time in German.

[image: An example]

Does anyone know what triggers this and how it can be turned off?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/f99d14b9-c889-419f-9252-835bec7c7393),

> Compiler messages come from the .NET Framework, so they are controlled by your OS language settings and whether or not you have any .NET Framework language packs installed.
>   To make the compiler messages change to other language, one simple way that you could try is to uninstall the .NET Framework language pack from your system.

Comment: Uninstalling the language pack(s) only leads to the case where the same warning / error appears *twice* in one language (english). It must be some quirk with the visual studio compiler, rather than something with the localization...

Comment: Oh, I see. I haven't had this error before. You say it only happens in *some* projects, so might it have to do with the .csproj or other metadata files?